# How to achieve webservice testing automation through programming/coding

Tags: c#, web-services, testing, asp.net-web-api

I know these questions have been asked many times , I am still looking for an answer that satisfies my question. please have a look at below points what I am looking for:

1. First thing , How to achieve that through programming. for web automation I am using specflow C#. do i need to create unit tests for the web service testing ? what can be done through programming ? soapUI is ruled out as its already used by manual testers.
2. Are there any available frameworks for these ?
3. Please give me links and examples supporting them.

I know its a broad question. but I do need some help from everyone so that I start in the right direction on API testing.

Comment: I fear your question will be closed as too broad. Also, don't use the `api` tag; you probably need to use `web-api` or even better `asp.net-web-api`.

Comment: before it does, i need some answers!!

Comment: Please update your question with some of the research you have been doing. Are you familiar with unit testing? Do you already know of any frameworks which you could use? Have you already checked out some examples? 
There is no such thing as "the right direction", it all depends on your specific needs, and as long as those are not entirely clear this question can not be properly answered. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your absolute first port of call is to understand the web service you are testing. Do you have valid XML you can submit to the web service? If so, store it somewhere and create a step that obtains it from the folder. Use that XML as your test case and iterate through each file in the folder. Each XML file should be different based on what you want the tests to cover.

Generally, web service testing will include logging response times, sending differing flavors of XML as test cases (alter the content of the nodes to cover different triggers), and checking for particular values in your responses.

A very high level and implicit Scenario could look like this (based on something I did once):

```
Scenario Outline: Submit Requests to Web Service
    Given I have XML file '<XML_Case>'
    And I submit a 'POST' request
    Then I should receive a response from the Web Service
    And the response will include a 'ResponseId' in the 'Header' section
    And the response will include a 'RequestId' in the 'Body' section
    And the 'Complete' node in the 'Body' section will return the value of 'True'

Examples:    
 |XML_Case                         |                      
 | C:\TestData\test1.xml           |
 | C:\TestData\test2.xml           |
 | etc...                          |
```

To drive this, there are many approaches in C#. To start you off, you could check for the XML file and convert it into your XML request via something like this as a step definition:

```
[Given(@"I have XML file '(.*)'")]
 public void GivenIHaveXMLFile(string fileName)
    {
        //Checks if file exists 
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            var requestXml = CreateXMLInstance(fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("No XML file found in specified location");
        }                    
    }
```

The `CreateXMLInstance` method used in that code would load the XML from the file path and could be like this:

```
 public XmlDocument CreateXmlInstance(string xmlPath)
    {
        //Loads XML from file path
        XmlDocument request = new XmlDocument();
        request.Load(xmlPath);
        return request;
    }
```

You've essentially created your first few steps and could store the `requestXml` variable as a field or in Specflow's `ScenarioContext` for use later when you do the web service calls.

There is obviously a lot more to consider but this might send you in the right direction.